# Listener in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, file-io, actionlistener, jtextpane

I am using `JTextPane` in Swing Application. Here i get problem that when i open a file and read its content to the JtextPane it don't call Document Listener.

Which `Listener` should i add in JTextPane for reading file?

```
File file=new JFileChooser().getSelectedFile();
input = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(
        file)));
jTextPane1.read(input, "READING FILE :-)");
```

and here is the `DocumentListener`:

```
jTextPane1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        public String getText() {
            int caretPosition = jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength();
            Element root = jTextPane1.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            for (int i = 2; i < root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) + 2; i++) {
                text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }
            return text;
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            jTextArea1.setText(getText());
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            jTextArea1.setText(getText());
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            jTextArea1.setText(getText());
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're already trying to use a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: yah, but its not working Why ?

Comment: If you would like help maybe you should add more information... What have you tried? What information are you receiving in error messages or a traceback. People will not just do your work for you if you don't give them any assistance.

Comment: Document is model for JTextComponents, DocumenListener is for listening changes in Document, please is there reason to send text (correctly by using read()) from one JTextComponent to another???,

Comment: Actually i wants that when i read a file and put there contents to the `jTextPane`, it shoule be count the line in the `jTextPane` and update in the `jTextarea`. But it is not being done. why ?

Comment: show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2):

The read() method uses `EditorKit's` Reader which in turn can recreate `Document` instance. It's faster to create a new `Document` rather than remove() all content and add it back to the old one. Try to compare the instances before and after read.

If they are different check whether the listener instance is added to the new Document instance and readd if it's not attached.

Comment: But How can we keep new instance's `reference id` of the `Document` for adding to the `addDocumentListener`?

Comment: Check what is returned by getDocument() before and after setText()